# separate whole numbers and decimals from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text string that can be as follows `let str = '10x2.34'` from which I would like to get only the numbers so try the following:

```
str.match(/\d+/g)
```

This ignores the characters and returns the numbers to me, but it only works for whole numbers, so how could I get the whole numbers and decimals, which can come in the following ways: `let str = '10x2.34'` or `let str = '10x2,34'`

Comment: Add the additional characters you want to capture to the character class : `'10x2.34'.match(/[\d.,]+/g)`

Comment: If you format is always in the form you say, then regex might be overkill.  Something like -> `'10x2,34'.split('x').map(m => parseFloat(m.replace(',','.')))` might work, and this also converts into numbers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match digits with `\d` and punctuation with `\.` or `,` :

```
str.match(/[\d\.,]+/g)
```

```js
const regex = /[\d\.,]+/g
console.log( "10x2.34".match(regex) ) // ["10","2.34"]
console.log( "10x2,34".match(regex) ) // ["10","2,34"]
```

Comment: Note that `.` doesn't behave as a meta-character while found inside a character class and therefore doesn't need to be escaped in that context. The backslash doesn't hurt either, so it's a matter how whether you prefer consistency or conciseness

Comment: Ah, you're right, I could have used `/[\d.,]+/g`, it would still have matched a dot and not "any character".